# How can i intersection two ActiveRecord Relation objects by rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to find the intersection result of two ActiveRecord Relation objects.
This is my Controller

```
if params.has_key?(:car_insurance_type_id)
  car_insurance_type = CarInsuranceType.find_by(id: params[:car_insurance_type_id])
else
  car_insurance_type = CarInsuranceType.find_by(id: 1)
end

@breadcrumb_title = car_insurance_type.title

car_insurance_objects_private = car_insurance_type.car_insurance_objects

if params.has_key?(:car_model_id)
  car_model_search = CarModel.find_by(id: params[:car_model_id])

  if car_model_search
    car_insurance_objects_from_model = car_model_search.car_insurance_objects
  end

end

car_insurance_objects_private = car_insurance_objects_private & car_insurance_objects_from_model
```

But "&" method didn't work for ActiveRecord object

This is my model

```
class CarInsuranceType < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :car_insurance_objects ,dependent: :destroy

end

class CarInsuranceObject < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :insurance_company
  belongs_to :car_insurance_type
  has_and_belongs_to_many :car_models

end

class CarModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :car_brand
  has_and_belongs_to_many :car_insurance_objects ,dependent: :destroy

end
```

So how can i find the intersection result between two CarInsuranceObject that one belongs_to car_insurance_type and another one that has_and_belongs_to_many car_models?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need to query DB for `CarInsuranceObject`'s of specified `CarInsuranceType` and `CarModel`.
Why not to simplify all this stuff:

```
car_insurance_type_id = params[:car_insurance_type_id] || 1
car_insurance_objects_private = car_model_search.car_insurance_objects.where(car_insurance_type_id: car_insurance_type_id)
```

Btw, there is really long names for variables.

Comment: long variable names are more descriptive and given that nearly every modern code editor has name completion there's no pain in working with the long names.